# How do I get rid of this WPF/XAML ListBox Padding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, wpf-controls

I'm having some trouble learning WPF, I've set up a custom UserControl like so:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LobbyApp" x:Class="LobbyApp.ChatPanel" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="600">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChatMessage}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>Auto</ColumnDefinition.Width>
                    <ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup>Date</ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup>
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>Auto</ColumnDefinition.Width>
                    <ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup>Who</ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup>
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>*</ColumnDefinition.Width>
                </ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGridCell BorderThickness="0" Content="{Binding Timestamp}" Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" Foreground="LightCyan"/>
            <DataGridCell BorderThickness="0" Content="{Binding Who}" Grid.Column="1" Background="Black" Foreground="LightBlue"/>
            <DataGridCell BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding What, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </DataGridCell>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding History}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Magenta" Padding="0"/>
```

Most of that I think doesn't matter, just including it for completeness. The interesting bit is I see the magenta background outside the scrollbars, like the listbox content and it's scrollbars are actually padded inside the listbox. It looks like this:

[image: ListBox Padding]

I see the outer magenta even if the listbox is a reasonable size, it's just easier to see when you shrink it small like that.

I've tried every margin/padding on every element I can to get rid of the magenta, but I can't seem to. I don't know what is causing that, or how to 'fix' it. I'll probably simplify my example down to the most basic parts but thought I'd post first since maybe it's just a dumb obvious answer. My apologies if so.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ListBox has a hard coded value of '1' for the Border Padding.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border Name="Bd"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Padding="1">
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  Focusable="false">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

So you can either modify the template yourself, or just hack it like below :

```
void OnListBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((ListBox)sender, 0) as Border;
        if(border != null)
        {
            border.Padding = new Thickness(0);
        }
    }
```

The above makes an assumption that you are using the default windows aero theme. If you change theme, or indeed if the aero theme gets changed, it may break.